# How could I get hour from the number stored as 630 & 2030 which means 06:30 & 20:30 respectively

Tags: sas

I have a data where time variables have value stored as 630 & 2030 etc and I need to fetch hours from time variable by using SAS code. (from given directory  - 630 & 2030 means 06:30 & 20:30)

Comment: can SAS divide by 100 and keep the remainder? If so, where's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, as John Dvorak suggests, is to divide by 100 and use the integer / remainder to derive the hour / minute values.  Convert that to seconds to get an actual time value, which can be formatted as such in SAS.

```
data want;
infile cards;
input rawdata; /* get raw values */
mins=mod(rawdata/100,2)*100; /* extract mins */
hours=round(rawdata/100,1); /* extract hours */
hhmm=(hours*60*60)+(mins*60); /* convert to seconds */
format hhmm hhmm5.; /* format as time */
put hours= mins= hhmm=; /* print to log */
cards;
630
2030
;run;
```

returns:

> hours=6 mins=30 hhmm=6:30
>    hours=20 mins=30 hhmm=20:30

[image]